# Why are tags lower cased?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why are tags lower-cased/not capitalized while most of them represent names/trademarks and should be upper-cased/capitalized.

Example:

**windows** should be  **Windows**

**firemonkey** should be **FireMonkey**

**delphi** should be **Delphi**

**java** should be **Java**

**matlab** should be  **MATLAB**

I mean the tags are not following the correct spelling of the original trade mark.

**Edit:**  I think you got me wrong there, this is what I'm asking:

Why is the tag for MATLAB written like `matlab` and not `MATLAB`?

Comment: The tags also use hyphens instead of spaces so I always figured the 3rd point Daniel mentions was part of it. I do sympathize with you: I wish it was easier to get to the tag pages when editing a question. The best way right now is to either open them in a new tab before editing the question or (and I find this better) open the post for editing in a new tab.

Comment: It is one of the unfortunate aspects of Stack Overflow, and it will never be changed due to inertia.

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange: [Is there any reason why tags are lower-cased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216225/21960)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of a few:

- Consistency
- Historical context
- Simplified, faster code in (for string comparisons):

  - C# web tier,
  - ElasticSearch
  - JavaScript front-end

Comment: What do you mean by Simplified code

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout with string comparisions

Comment: As for historical context though, when speaking of "Web 2.0" tags, it looks like delicious (supposedly the one who introduced them) _did_ support casing ( [example](https://archive.is/20130102102058/http://delicious.com/tag/wiki) ). I don't know how it handled them though (I never used it).